# How is the side-polarity of the myosin filament in myofibril maintained?

Tags: physiology, muscles, medicine

If myosin molecules are the properly oriented relative to their position in the myosin filaments, the sarcomere is not functional. But how is the orientation of the myosin molecules determined? Why is there a symmetry in the arrangement of myosin molecules in the myosin filament? And are there any diseases associated with the improper arrangement of myosin molecules?

Comment: There are a lot of other proteins like titin and dystrophin to name few which maintain the sarcomeric structure. But got no clue of anything specific. Its important to know that it's not just the actin and myosin floating in the muscles as textbook diagrams show.